# Share link from iPhone mobile platform

Tags: ios, facebook, hyperlink, share

we have an iPhone application that can share to Facebook but we have a problem with one of our share links (all the links use the same code).

The code is the following:

```
NSString *fullUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%@", 
[campaignToShare.shareurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullUrl]];
```

When we call the openURL method with the parameter: http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://open.mikz.com/upvudd

we get it translated on safari (also opera) to the following url:
http://m.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fopen.mikz.com%2Fupvudd&_rdr

which does not work, however if use the url before the redirect to m.facebook (on the computer) then it works.

Is the code that we have written wrong or have we found a bug for iOS + m.facebook.com?

Obs: It works for all the other links that we have, the only differens on those links are that they have a different code (instead of upvudd).

Comment: try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385363/publishing-links-to-users-wall-using-facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: We are not using Facebook sdk (at the moment) and would like to get the problem solved without using it.