# Facebook sdk post on wall on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I have a problem with implementing Facebook posting on wall in my iPhone application.
I installed SDK and linked framework
login is working fine. here's the code:

```
-(IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"loginButtonPressed: called");

    AppDelegate *appdel=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appdel.facebookSession=[[FBSession alloc] init];
    [appdel.facebookSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, 
                                                     FBSessionState status, 
                                                     NSError *error)
    {
        //
    }];
}
```

But I have a problem with posting message on user's wall. Here's the code:

```
-(IBAction)likeButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"likeButtonPressed: called");
    // Post a status update to the user's feedm via the Graph API, and display an alert view 
    // with the results or an error.

    NSString *message = @"test message";
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:message forKey:@"message"];

    // use the "startWith" helper static on FBRequest to both create and start a request, with
    // a specified completion handler.
    [FBRequest startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                       parameters:params
                       HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                    [self showAlert:message result:result error:error];
                }];

}
```

Help me please. What's wrong with my code? Or should I add some permissions to login request?

Comment: You forgot to describe the actual _problem/error_.

Comment: Is the log in form displayed when you initiate your facebook post?

Comment: I've got a message in debug: `Error: HTTP status code: 400` and `The operation couldn't be completed. (com.facebook.FBIOSSDK error 5.)`in ÙIAlertView`

Comment: @user1385666 I believe this error is "{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}"

Comment: I created a simple project in GitHub as an example using the FB SDK + iOS 6 and Storyboards. The app can post in the timeline: [FB SDK + Storyboards with Publish to Feed](https://github.com/Belzebul/fb-sdk-storyboards) Cheers!

Comment: any sample demo is available for posting on facebook without using dialog or pop up

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this code worked for me.
First we must

```
#import <FBiOSSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

then

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FBRequestConnection *requestConnection;
```

and of course do not forget to synthesize:

```
@synthesize requestConnection;
```

the code itself:

```
-(IBAction)likeButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"likeButtonPressed: called");
    // FBSample logic
    // Check to see whether we have already opened a session.
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        // login is integrated with the send button -- so if open, we send
        [self postOnWall];
    }
    else
    {
        [FBSession sessionOpenWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil]
                                completionHandler:
             ^(FBSession *session, 
               FBSessionState status, 
               NSError *error)
            {
                 // if login fails for any reason, we alert
                 if (error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"    login failed");
                     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                     message:error.localizedDescription
                                                                    delegate:nil
                                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [alert show];
                     // if otherwise we check to see if the session is open, an alternative to
                     // to the FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE helper-macro would be to check the isOpen
                     // property of the session object; the macros are useful, however, for more
                     // detailed state checking for FBSession objects
                 }
                 else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status))
                 {
                     NSLog(@"    sending post on wall request...");
                     // send our requests if we successfully logged in
                     [self postOnWall]; 
                 }
             }];
    };
}

- (void)postOnWall
{
    NSNumber *testMessageIndex=[[NSNumber alloc] init];
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"testMessageIndex"]==nil)
    {
        testMessageIndex=[NSNumber numberWithInt:100];
    }
    else
    {
        testMessageIndex=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"testMessageIndex"];
    };
    testMessageIndex=[NSNumber numberWithInt:[testMessageIndex intValue]+1];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:testMessageIndex forKey:@"testMessageIndex"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    // create the connection object
    FBRequestConnection *newConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

    // create a handler block to handle the results of the request for fbid's profile
    FBRequestHandler handler =
    ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        // output the results of the request
        [self requestCompleted:connection forFbID:@"me" result:result error:error];
    };

    // create the request object, using the fbid as the graph path
    // as an alternative the request* static methods of the FBRequest class could
    // be used to fetch common requests, such as /me and /me/friends
    NSString *messageString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"wk test message %i", [testMessageIndex intValue]];
    FBRequest *request=[[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:FBSession.activeSession graphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:messageString forKey:@"message"] HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // add the request to the connection object, if more than one request is added
    // the connection object will compose the requests as a batch request; whether or
    // not the request is a batch or a singleton, the handler behavior is the same,
    // allowing the application to be dynamic in regards to whether a single or multiple
    // requests are occuring
    [newConnection addRequest:request completionHandler:handler];

    // if there's an outstanding connection, just cancel
    [self.requestConnection cancel];

    // keep track of our connection, and start it
    self.requestConnection = newConnection;    
    [newConnection start];
}

// FBSample logic
// Report any results.  Invoked once for each request we make.
- (void)requestCompleted:(FBRequestConnection *)connection
                 forFbID:fbID
                  result:(id)result
                   error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"request completed");

    // not the completion we were looking for...
    if (self.requestConnection &&
        connection != self.requestConnection)
    {
        NSLog(@"    not the completion we are looking for");
        return;
    }

    // clean this up, for posterity
    self.requestConnection = nil;

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"    error");
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        // error contains details about why the request failed
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"   ok");        
    };
}
```

Comment: This was a Expected answer, well written.But, FBRequestConnection does not provide any UI like FBDialog. So, if we want FaceBookFramework to handle it then what should be its alternative.

Comment: @Mobilhunterz: Can you share your code with us? This worked for me for the very first run. Might be you are missing something. Share your code snippet with us so that we can help you better.

Comment: will you answer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22088022/sharing-hyperlink-with-facebook-from-ios-app)?

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
        NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:
                            [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.facebook.com"]];

for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
    [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}
NSString *FBBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your message you want to post"];
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:image naemif you want to post]];
FBFeedPost *post = [[FBFeedPost alloc] initWithPhoto:img name:FBBody];
[post publishPostWithDelegate:self];
[[UIAppDelegate indicator] startAnimating];
IFNNotificationDisplay *display = [[IFNNotificationDisplay alloc] init];
display.type = NotificationDisplayTypeLoading;
display.tag = NOTIFICATION_DISPLAY_TAG;
```

Answer (score 2):

you should set Permissions:"status_update".

like this :

```
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"status_update"]];
```

or

```
FBSession *fbSession = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"status_update"]];
```