# publishing on my facebook wall using new sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am using the new Facebook SDK to publish on my wall by following [their instructions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/)

I got authorization from the app, but when i try to publish i am getting an error
`Error: HTTP status code: 400` below i am posting my code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.postParams =
 [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
 @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
 @"https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
 @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
 @"build apps.", @"caption",
 @"testing for my app.", @"description",
 nil]; 

[self.postParams setObject:@"hgshsghhgsls" forKey:@"message"];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(IBAction)Post{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];


[FBRequestConnection   startWithGraphPath:@"me/Mac" parameters:self.postParams HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                        completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id result,NSError *error) {
                            NSString *alertText;
                             if (error) {
                             alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"error: domain = %@, code = %d, des = %d",error.domain, error.code,error.description];
                             } 
                             else 
                             {
                             alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posted action, id: %@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]];
                             }
                             // Show the result in an alert
                             [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result" message:alertText delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                             otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
                        }]; 




}
```

What am i doing wrong here and any suggestion will be great and this new SDK is a beta version ? or a complete one ?

Comment: can you please post the whole error line? Do a NSLog(@"%@", error); Then you see the whole description, why it is throwing the 400 error. Or post the message of your alert output...

Comment: 2012-08-30 14:33:05.225 NewFbLogin[1275:fe03] Error: HTTP status code: 400

Comment: Sorry for this silly question, but you have a valid login and facebook session? Maybe follow this tut: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/

Comment: this is nslog and error is large enough i could not post completely .Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x6b8ab10 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey=<CFBasicHash 0x68cc3a0 [0x1502b48]>{type = mutable dict, count = 2,

Comment: Another question: What is me/Mac? It has to be me/feed, if you wish to post sth...

Comment: yeah i have valid login and fbsession i have followed the same tutorial

Comment: ok Mac is my app name i thought it has to be replaced let me check with feed and i will get back tou

Comment: ok, AppName has nothing to do with feed. You do not post something in your App (as your App only is an a door for an iOS App to authenticate), but anyone, who uses your app will post something out of the iOS App (after authenticating with his fb account) on his facebook wall, showing, that it came from your facebook app

Comment: ok so i changed to feed and still problem is there what i am doing wrong i did not get.if you knowanything just let me know

Comment: Normally you have something like this: `Facebook *facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:FB_APP_ID urlSchemeSuffix:FB_APP_SUFFIX andDelegate:self];` and then you have to use the same object to do say: `[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];` But I guess you are using facebook SDK 3. This would be for 2

Comment: with previous sdk i was doing like that but this new sdk i did not try can we discuss this in chat room because it is getting very long here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16021/discussion-between-fab1n-and-answerme)

Answer (score 12):

If you run into any issues, try turning on logging by adding this code before the request call you're interested in debugging:

`[FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet 
                                   setWithObjects:FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests,
                                   FBLoggingBehaviorFBURLConnections, 
                                   nil]];`

Answer (score 4):

finally i solved the problem for that i have to change the Auth Token Parameter to URLFragment in my app permission page then it is working

Comment: Hi AnswerMe, can you explain a bit more what the solution was? When you say your app permission page, do you mean on developer.facebook.com? Perhaps step by step what you did? Thanks.

Comment: yes on developer.facebook.com i selected my app then edit settings and in next page i selected permissions which is on the left hand side and in that Auth Token Parameter option i changed to URL Fragment option .thats all i have done and it is working

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had the same error and solved it with the correct answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540372/facebook-sdk-post-on-wall-on-iphone-app) but maybe this will help someone. I don't know why someone down-voted you.

Comment: I changed this parameter, but still no luck :(

Comment: Same with me. Any of you solve it yet? Would be great if you could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i used this framework for my project. it works properly. this is my related code

```
   -(IBAction)logIn:(id)sender;
{
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    [appdelegate sessionOpener];
}
else {
    [self loginHelp];
}
```

and my sessionOpener function is;

```
 -(void) sessionOpener
```

{

```
[FBSession sessionOpenWithPermissions:nil
                    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                        FBSessionState status,
                                        NSError *error) {
                        // session might now be open.
                        if (!error) {
                            [self.viewController loginHelp];
                        }
                    }];

 NSLog(@"%d", FBSession.activeSession.isOpen);
NSLog(@"%@", FBSession.activeSession.description );
```

}

it works for me. may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

check  Session Publish Permissions.

its worked me fine.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"email", nil]
                                   defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                      allowLoginUI:YES
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                 }];
```