# Publishing picture to facebook page as admin

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have problem publishing a photo from ios app to facebook page **as the page's admin**. The only thing I can publish as admin is a status message.

Here what I did.

```
// get access token first
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/__facebook_page_id__?fields=access_token" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    // make sure its not nil
    if ([result valueForKey:@"access_token"] != nil) {
        NSString *accessToken = [result objectForKey:@"access_token"];

        NSLog(@"Access token: %@", accessToken);

        NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [params setObject:@"This is some status message" forKey:@"message"];
        [params setObject:accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/__facebook_page_id__/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

        }];
    }

}];
```

**The above code successfully publish to facebook page as the admin**. Since I need to publish a photo, I need to change the grap path to /facebook_page_id/photos.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imagePreview.image) forKey:@"picture"];
[params setObject:@"This is some description" forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/__facebook_page_id__/photos"] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];
```

The above code is successfully published, but not as admin. Eventhough I am using the page's access token.

I thought the path fb_page_id/photos was broken, so I tried to use the fb_page_id/feed and send other fields such as link, picture, etc. But still, it posted as the user, not the page's admin.

Please let me know if I am doing wrong.

Some Information:
- Deployment target: 5.1 and above
- Facebook SDK Version: 3.7

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193915/publishing-on-my-facebook-wall-using-new-sdk?rq=1.

Comment: i thought i don't have any problem publishing to facebook as the user. the only problem is i seem can't post as the page's admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Just in case somebody having the same problem, here is what I am doing.

1. You will need a Page's access_token by accessing `/page_id?fields=access_token`

   [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@?fields=access_token", FB_PAGE_ID] completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

   ```
   // if the access_token is not there, the user might not able to post. check the permission
   if ([result valueForKey:@"access_token"] != nil) {
       NSString *accessToken = [result objectForKey:@"access_token"];
   }
   ```

   }];
2. After getting the Page's access_token, you need to post the image using REST API. Here I am using AFNetworking, and manually upload the image.

   if ([result valueForKey:@"access_token"] != nil) {
       NSString *accessToken = [result objectForKey:@"access_token"];

   ```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com"];
   AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:url];

   // parameter
   NSDictionary *params = @{@"access_token": accessToken, @"message": message};

   // image data
   NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imagePreview.image, 1);

   // create Request and upload the image
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/photos/", [defaults stringForKey:@"fb_page_id"]] parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
       [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"source" fileName:accessToken mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
   }];

   // publish!
   AFJSONRequestOperation *json = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request1 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

       // IMAGE PUBLISHED!!!

   } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
       // SOMETHING WRONG HAPPEN
   }];
   [json start];
   ```

   }

Don't ask me why I'm using REST API, I tried everything using their SDK, but its always failed.

I hope somebody will find it usefull for this piece of codes.