# Opening Ios App from Safari with custom URL scheme

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am opening my iOS app with custom URL Scheme which is added in my .Plist from native message app. My custom URL is xyzapp in .plist. When I received message like xyzapp://verificationcode/12 (this test looks like a link) in message app and I touch the text it open my iOS app and I handle it with appdelegete file.

My problem is that I am sharing my code i .e  xyzapp://verificationcode/12 with Facebook or Google Twitter plush and touch this text from there no event happens.

Please suggest something so I can open my iOS app form Facebook or Google or Twitter.

Comment: Have you tried to open schema link using safari to open your app? Does it work?

Comment: yes if i write my schema link on safari address and click go it open my app. but when i click same text of facebook or google + it does nothing . on facebook my schema looks simple text .. so how can i post my schema link text like a touchable lind from my app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can share a standard url like "http://yourdomain.com/appurl", and then you can redirect to the url "Connectgolf://verificationcode/12" with Javascript or other web languages. I think facebook, google or twitter can not detect what "Connectgolf" is and they will ignore it.

just a example.

youserver.com/myapp.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>redirect</title>

</head>
<body id="" onload="">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "Connectgolf://verificationcode/12";
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @user2906829  yes, that must be a simple text, because facebook don't know what it is, so you need to give a url that facebook can detect it, such as http or https, but there is one step before you share  .you should link the http to your own server and the url should redirct to the "Connectgolf"

Comment: ok you are saying i have to write when posting like http://myserver.com like this facebook will make it clickeable...but and it redirect to my my app . please give some example

Comment: maybe you can try the method by @LongNV

Answer (score 0):

Facebook/Twitter can not recognize your text as a link. If you share url schema from your app to facebook using Facebook SDK, try this one:
[Publishing links to user's wall using Facebook iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385363/publishing-links-to-users-wall-using-facebook-ios-sdk?lq=1)
I think Twitter/Google may have api to do this.
In case you use UIActivityViewController to share via twitter/facebook, use below code:

```
NSString *text = @"<html><body><br\\>Go here - <a href='http://apple.com'>APPLE</a></body>    </html>";
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"];
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]     initWithActivityItems:@[text, URL, imageToSave] applicationActivities:nil];
```